# How to create "out of office" calendar with the capability to reassign task?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I want to create "out of office" calendar with the capability to reassign task.

**E.G.**

All admin users must have a common calendar containing all the information about their staff members who are/will be on leave. At the time of assigning tasks, Admin should get an alert if the assigned staff member is/will be on leave so that he could reassign the task to anyone else in team.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: alert means email notification?

Comment: alert as an prompt or some custom error message to show that the particular member is on leave !

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using workflow. You need to create `event receiver` on task list and add `Item Adding` event. Do code for checking assigned user is on leave on specific date range in calendar list, If get result more than 0,cancel event, so user can not save item and get event receiver cancellation message with your custom message.